# What is this circular rod with wired wrapped 'coil' and ceramic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, components, identification, coil, ferrite

Found this in a battery compartment, glued with white gum, however not connected to anything.

It is a ferrite circular rod of 3cm, diameter 6mm and wrapped with some wire (12/13 windings) and connected to a ceramic capacitor of unknown size (very small capacity I think).

I have really no clue what it supposed to be, any ideas?

[image: device]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using 3 pieces of information to suggest a hypothesis as to the function of that device:

1. It's an [LC tank circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit), and so will have an RF resonant frequency (which could be calculated from the values of the inductor and capacitor).
2. This LC circuit is not connected to anything and so its function must be self-contained, not part of the equipment it was found inside.
3. It was effectively hidden, by being in the battery compartment (of whatever this equipment is).

Hypothesis:

Perhaps it's a device which allows the device to be detected as it passes a suitable RF transmitter e.g. as used by some [shoplifting detector systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_article_surveillance), hire shops & even office asset detectors?

Although current systems using that technique can have [flat stickers with the L and C formed internally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ws_rfrp.jpg), they use the same basic technique of an LC tank circuit as in your photo, whose presence can be detected when it is "excited" by a transmitter tuned to the LC circuit's resonant frequency. Yours could be a home-made equivalent, or an early version of that technology.

Whatever the equipment where you found it actually is, that LC circuit would allow someone to detect when it passed a certain point (where a suitably tuned transmitter was fitted).

Comment: +1, good hypothesis, though without more info it's hard to know exactly what the purpose is.  I can't come up with a better theory though.

Comment: Excellent explanation, +1. It's a second hand device that has it in the battery compartment, so it sits there for many years, I think. I don't know the history of the device, picked it up from the trash disposal (dumpster) and by opening it, I found this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a loopstick antenna to me:

[image]

Ferrite core antennas, known as loopsticks, are widely used as antennas for radio receivers, particularly for AM broadcast band radios. This is done by winding a coil or loop, generally with tightly-spaced turns over one end of a ferrite rod or bar. The ferrite has the effect of concentrating and intensifying the received magnetic field inside the loop. Like other forms of loop antennas, loopstick antennas are relatively free from RF noise, as they react to the magnetic portion of the RF energy received and are relatively immune to the electrical component, which is prone to noise caused by electrical sources.

From [HERE](http://radio-timetraveller.blogspot.com/2011/01/unassuming-antenna-ferrite-loopstick.html)

Why it would be in a battery compartment unconnected to anything is a mystery to me.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. A mistery for me either. Well, if it is an antenna, why it is not connected and the 'coil' shorted by an capacitor?

Comment: The coil isn't "shorted" by the capacitor; the two make a resonant circuit at some frequency. It could be some kind of "passive booster" that improves the performance of a smallish internal antenna (that's probably close to the spot where you found it glued). What kind of equipment did you find it in?